# Play framework 2.1 can't use custom modules

Tags: module, dependencies, playframework-2.1

I'm not able to use a module which I created by myself. I do everything like the following description:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/writing-modules-play-2-get

But there are little changes which shouldn't have any influence of the functionality: I don't change the project-struktur and i create separates projects in different folders. I think I should describe my steps for using and creating my own module and perhaps anyone see my mistake:

I create one project with play new testapp (workspace/testapp). Then i create an other projekt with play new testmodul (workspace/testmodul). Then i go to the testmodul and delete the route-file and the content of the application.conf. Then i create a class called "Tester" with the method test. (a simple system.out) After that i exceute "clean", "compile" and "publish-local" in the testmodul-folder.

In my understanding the modul ist published in the local repository of play and every application which want to use this module will have access to the local repository version of the module.

Now I go to the testapp and create the dependencies in the Build.scala. After that i go to the default-Application.class and add the line "Tester.test();". Then I excecute the dependencies command and try to compile.

After that i get the error, "can't find symbol". It seemed to be that the testapp don't know the Tester.class and that means that the testapp don't know the module.
But I don't know why.

Has anybody an idea?

Edit:
Perhaps I should display my dependencie config of the testapp:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore
    ,javaJdbc
    ,javaEbean
    ,"testmodul" % "testmodul_2.10" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here   
    resolvers += "Local Play Repository" at "file://C:/play-2.1.0/repository/local"   
  )
```

Comment: Do you use Eclipse, cannot find symbol looks like IDE error, try `play eclipse` after running `clean` etc

Comment: Yes, i use eclipse and I did the eclipse command before. I think it's not an eclipse error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the solution above wasn't right, but i found a solution. I found out that in the documentation of the playframework "modules" called "subprojects" there I found how to include modules. (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/SBTSubProjects)
But I think the other way of "global" modules should also be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
resolvers += "Local Play Repository" at "file://C:/play-2.1.0/repository/local"
```

To

```
resolvers += "Local Play Repository" at "file://play-2.1.0/repository/local"
```

Just remove the C:/ .It worked for me. Check this http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=363.